# Download progression keeps creating new line

Tags: google-colaboratory

How to stop download progression from creating new line. I just want it only in one line.

**Here's the code**

```
while (handle.status().state 
!= lt.torrent_status.seeding):
s = handle.status()
state_str = ['queued', 'checking', 'downloading metadata', \
        'downloading', 'finished', 'seeding', 'allocating']
print ('%.2f%% ... (UP: %.1f kb/s DOWN: %.1f kB/s seed: %d) %s ' % \
        (s.progress * 100, s.download_rate / 1000, s.upload_rate / 1000, \
        s.num_peers, state_str[s.state]))
time.sleep(5)

end = time.time()
print(handle.name(), "COMPLETE")

print("Elapsed Time: 
",int((end-begin)//60),"min :", int((end-begin)%60), "sec")

print(datetime.datetime.now())
```